# Razor formatting-MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using this to display a label and value for the label from the Action controller.

```
@Html.Label("Label to be Displayed:"):
  @Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id =Model.id })
```

But, Label comes on one line and Value for the Label comes on the other line.

What should I do to display the label and value in a single line;

Like this:

**Label to be Displayed**: **Value from the ActionController**

Comment: what does the resulting html look like?

Comment: Show your html and then we can tell you what's best to style your html helpers to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can also use `div` with specifying classes

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>@Html.Label("Label to be Displayed:"):</td>
   <td>@Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id =Model.id })</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not a solution to use table for such a task. Of course you can, but that is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, add this to your css.

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Long answer:

http://designfestival.com/position-text-labels-on-forms-using-css/

Try not to use tables for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `Html.Action` is resulting in some kind of html that you have styled as `display: block;` or it is a block element that comes out from the action. If the `Action` just returns text it shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: @Pero: then you whould have to style that as well, or don't use a label the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Html.Label("Label to be Displayed:")
@Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id =Model.id },new {@style= "float:right"})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML table for it. In MVC You can easily manage design by HTML. Please try following code.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>@Html.Label("Label to be Displayed:"):</td>
   <td>@Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id =Model.id })</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not a solution to use table for such a task. Of course you can, but that is not the way to go.

Comment: @Thomas Jansson .. May I know what is the best solution for it and it should work in all scenario?

Comment: @alok-dida, It is hard to say since you don't see the surrounding html. But I would go for `<div class="someclass">@Html.Label("label to be displayed:"): <span class="actionspan">@Html.Action(...)</span></div>`